# Search issue on patent # US5269144A for Michael J. Holihan

Tags: search

I was the original inventor of patent #[US5269144A](https://www.google.com/patents/US5269144), however; I was added later due to a major oversight. When I search my name for patents, this patent does not show up? My name is shown if you click on "[View PDF](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US5269144.pdf)". Is it possible to remedy this in the Google Database?

Answer (score 0):

[Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) Searching by patent number 5269144 doesn't show you in there on the case data.  There was a correction in 1999 but it is not listed with any documents on PAIR.  Google uses data from the USPTO and in there you aren't listed as inventor on either the text or image data. These are the listed inventors:

STANLEY P. MILLER   NORTHVILLE, MI (US)

CRAIG L. SAVONEN    CARLTON, MI (US)

STEVEN M. WEISMAN   FARMINGTON HILL, MI (US)

DAVID P TASKY   AUBURN HILLS, MI (US)

JEFFREY S. HAWKINS  BURBANK, CA (US)

RICHARD E. WINSOR   BIRMINGHAM, MI (US)

I see the change in inventorship at the end of the PDF document.  I believe you need to have the original data changed at the USPTO in order to have Google correct it because they are only reporting what the patent office is telling them.